# Spaceplane simulating winged flight in the vacuum of space?

Tags: science-fiction, space-travel, spaceplane

If a spaceplane were to try to simulate the look of aerial flight in the vacuum, would it be difficult or easy for the pilot to manually simulate aerial maneuvers, using just a contemporary reaction control system, and make no use a computer.

I'm imagining a flight demonstration squadron in outer space.

Comment: Yes, it would be incredibly difficult, if not impossible, as their RCS thrusters would have to constantly correct for inertia that is otherwise dissipated by air resistance. At the very least the fuel requirements would be incredibly high.

Comment: Sub-orbital flight and orbital flight are two completely different beasts. This is not comparing apples to oranges, this is comparing octopuses to bycicles.

Comment: @Renan I understand that maneuvering in an atmosphere is completely different than in a vacuum.  I'm just curious if aerial flight in a vacuum could be simulated?

Comment: @stix That sounds like an answer.

Comment: Just as spaceflight is different from atmospheric flight, so too would a vacuum display team operate differently from an atmospheric display team. Use the medium to its own best advantage, rather than trying to get something that combines the downsides of both worlds.

Comment: @StarfishPrime. For the purpose of my story I would like to have a vacuum display team be able to reproduce the movements of atmosphere flight.  That it is not logical, yet the squadron is ordered to execute the flight that way, is an element of a scene.

Comment: Why the down votes?  Without an explanation I don't know what is wrong or how to make sure I don't repeat the same problem.

Comment: @Bob516 Is there any reason in particular that you've forbade the use of a computer?

Comment: @BladeWraith Its a minor plot point in the story.

Comment: @Bob516 Looks fine to me. I dont get it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on who you are trying to fool.

If you are trying to simulate aerial flight for a bunch of natural-space-born yokels who have never seen an aerial flight in their life, it's not too hard.  It's actually rather easy, for the same reasons as we accept aerial-like maneuvers in our movies -- we don't know any different.  It seems reasonably by our standards.

If you are trying to fool a computer algorithm that's designed to track aerial vehicles, it'll smoke you out in no time flat.  The inaccuracies which stem from trying to create the correct attitude and delta-V will stick out like a sore thumb to any reasonable Kalman filter.  Emulating the expected behaviors of an aero-vehicle is one thing.  Emulating the distribution of the errors is much harder, and real-life filters are sensitive to such errors.

Also, consider that aircraft have access to the air as a reaction mass; spacecraft are bound by the tyrany of the rocket equation.  Emulating the movement of aircraft is *exorbitantly* expensive, and the first sign that something is wrong is that the mass fraction of your craft is abysmally low because you have to waste so much of your precious delta-V to emulate being energy bound instead.  Your average Cessna has far more delta-V than the most advanced rocket we have designed.  A turbofan has an ISP on the order of 8x higher than a LOX/Hydrogen rocket, and on par with that of an ion thruster, but on the order of a million times more thrust than those ion thrusters.  (I talk about a turbofan because I can actually find the ISP numbers for one.  Nobody talks about specific of a prop plane engine... it's simply not a number which is interesting to anyone)

If you wanted to emulate the flight characteristics of a paper airplane soaring across the room, that's within the realm of an advanced space fighter.

As for pilots doing it, it's pretty absurd to think a pilot could manage to emulate *precisely* the behavior of an aerial vehicle.  However, one must give pilots credit.  If you tell them that their job is to do something insane, [they can pull out all the stops](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtZpcUj_wqQ).  Do not underestimate the capabilities of a pilot whose reputation as a cool kat is on the line.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot simulate atmospheric flight in the hard vacuum of outer space. The reason for that is because an atmosphere and a hard vacuum are mutually exclusive.

What keeps you flying in an atmospheric flight is the lift generated by flying through gases at high speed and largely deflecting said gas downwards through the usage of wings. Newton's third makes sure that your vessel is pushed up this way. You can then do all kinds of maneuvers by deflecting air in one way or another. For example, tilt your plane 90º to one side to make a very sharp turn in that direction. Guaranteed fun for the whole family!

In outer space, you are always orbiting something. It may be the Earth, the Sun, the Galaxy, the Local Cluster, whatever. What determines your path is your relative speed to the center of mass you are orbiting around. No amount of rotation in any direction will change your path. Accelerating prograde expands your orbit at the opposite point from where you are accelerating. Accelerating retrograde has the opposite effect. Accelerating normal or anti-normal tilts your plane of orbit, and accelerating radial or anti-radial rotates the whole orbit.

Notice that for a squadron to keep a formation, this means that each vessel in the squad is either on a different plane of orbit, a different height, or a different speed relative to the body they are orbiting. Most likely a mix of the three. Around a body like the Earth, this means that without constant non-liner acceleration any formation is broken within seconds as the distances and speeds involved mean hundreds of meters of relative speed among the members of the formation. By the way, the calculations for each ship acceleration is literal rocket-science; Your restriction against computers might make it impossible. Also in space fuel is at a premium. No atmosphere means you must carry your own oxidizer, and the rocket equation is a cruel mistress (i.e.: adding more and more fuel to a vessel gives it diminishing returns in autonomy). If this sounded too complex or abstract, try to some orbital docking in Kerbal Space Program and see for yourself.

Comment: Ignoring orbital dynamics for a moment, couldn't a ship moving through a vacuum simulate the banking turn of an aircraft with RCS thrusters?

Comment: I have a rudimentary understanding of orbital dynamics.  If the spacecraft had a constant non-linear acceleration, then could the ships appear to move as a squadron?

Comment: @Bob516 the answer to both of your comments is yes with a lot of handwaving or future tech, but only from the point of view of the pilots; And no if you forbid computers.